# Якобы — наречие или частица?

Tags: наречия, частица

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить часть речи слова "якобы": наречие или частица?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если слово *якобы* соединяет два предложения, то это союз; его можно заменить на *будто бы*, *как будто* :
*Ходили разговоры, якобы новый главный инженер метит на директорское кресло*.
В других случаях *якобы* является частицей практически с тем же смыслом - *будто*, *будто бы* :
*По записям в служебном журнале он якобы уехал раньше всех в тот день*,
*Форвард заявил судье, что он якобы не слышал свистка*.
Якобы ~~~ как бы.

Answer (score 0):

Среди наречий или частиц таких слов нет